# Replace String With hashmap value using java 8 stream

Tags: java, hashmap, java-8, java-stream

I have `String` and `HashMap` like below codes:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("ABC", "123");
    String test = "helloABC";
    map.forEach((key, value) -> {
        test = test.replaceAll(key, value);
    });
```

and I try to replace the string with the `HashMap` values, but this doesn't work because `test` is final and cannot be reassigned in the body of `forEach`.

So are there any solutions to replace `String` with `HashMap` using Java 8 Stream API?

Comment: `forEach()` is not synchronized. Your code does not compile because you cannot have a side effect on `message` from inside your lambda expression. Even if you could, all you'd get is `message` containing the last replacement on `test` for the last map entry in the map. Which is probably not what you want. Also because "last map entry" is non-deterministic for `HashMap`.

Comment: Ok Thanks, I got it. but what should I do to get all contents of test that already replaced?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As this cannot be made using only `forEach()` (`message` must be effectively final), workaround could be to create a final container (e. g. `List`) which stores a single `String` that is re-written:

```
final List<String> msg = Arrays.asList("helloABC");
map.forEach((key, value) -> msg.set(0, msg.get(0).replace(key, value)));
String test = msg.get(0);
```

Note that I changed `replaceAll()` to [`replace()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) because former works with regex, but judging by your code seems you need replacement by string itself (don't worry, despite of confusing name it also replaces *all* occurrences).

If you want exactly Stream API, you may use [`reduce()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-U-java.util.function.BiFunction-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) operation:

```
String test = map.entrySet()
                 .stream()
                 .reduce("helloABC", 
                         (s, e) -> s.replace(e.getKey(), e.getValue()), 
                         (s1, s2) -> null);
```

But take into account, that such reduction will work properly *only in serial (not parallel) stream*, where combiner function is never called (thus may be any).

Comment: I already tried it, but its seem so tricky. and how if we have many elements in Map?

Comment: @ChheaVanrin `0` refers to `List`, not to a `Map`. `forEach()` will process as much map entries as you have.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see it clearly :) . but it seem not so logic. I just  want to work with completely java 8 stream. Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 4):

This sort of a problem is not well-suited for Streams API.  The current incarnation of Streams is mainly directed at tasks that can be made parallel.  Perhaps support for this type of operation will be added in the future (see https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8133680).

One streams-based approach that you might find interesting is to reduce on functions rather than on the string:

```
Function<String, String> combined = map.entrySet().stream()
    .reduce(
        Function.identity(),
        (f, e) -> s -> f.apply(s).replaceAll(e.getKey(), e.getValue()),
        Function::andThen
    );

String result = combined.apply(test);
```

Comment: Seems that no chance to see `foldLeft` in Java-9. Unfortunately.

Comment: @TagirValeev I saw your efforts on core-lib mailing list a few months ago.  Thank you for trying.